# Virtual android device for Kivy application

Tags: android, python, virtual-machine

Is there an environment that supports virtual Android devices for Python app testing?

I'm using Kivy to develop a simple Python app and cannot find an environment to test application deployments that run/handle Python. The Android Studio is designed to handle Java but provides the functionality I am looking for by opening a virtual android device.

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with Kivy, but you can create and launch a virtual device from android studio or the command line once you have the android sdk installed. If Kivy builds an APK then you can deploy that apk to the virtual device using ADB or by dragging the APK into the virtual device window.

Comment: Kivy does have the ability per the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-android) to package an app. I'm not familiar with Android development (first attempt) but just wanted to test the simple "Hello World" idiom. Not familiar with ADB.

Comment: It looks like you can use Buildozer. You can also create a virtual device that has the play store if you want to use the process that involves installing the kivy launcher.

Comment: "You can also create a virtual device that has the play store if you want", is that in the docs??

Comment: Some of the images include the play store - there is an Android Studio doc on how to create an AVD here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#createavd